# How to have fixed number of element of *ngFor in side container during scroll

Tags: javascript, angular

I have used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45453578/8632727)  for loading large date inside container div. It works perfectly but It become over slow when it keep on appending element in the list as I scroll down.

So I want to update it to keep the elements fixed at any position on scroll. So I updated code as

```
  pageStart:number = 0;
  pageEnd:number = 50;
  pageHeight:number = 30;
  pageBuffer:number = 50;

onScroll( event, doc )
  {
    const scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
    const scrollHeight = event.target.scrollHeight;
    const offsetHeight = event.target.offsetHeight;
    const scrollPosition = scrollTop + offsetHeight;
    const scrollTreshold = scrollHeight - this.pageHeight;
    if( scrollPosition > scrollTreshold ){
      if(this.someLargeData.length>=this.pageEnd){
        this.pageEnd+= this.pageBuffer;
        this.pageStart+= this.pageBuffer; // added this to update pageStart
       }
    }
  }
```

By this way I can adjust content to have 50 elements as I scroll down.Now the problem is how to scroll up and get top elements as `this.pageEnd` and `this.pageStart` is only increasing.

So how to decrease `this.pageEnd` and `this.pageStart` on scroll up ?? to get top elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer.

If you know the total of the elements you want to load and the height.
You can use an invisible div element to force a scrollbar.
Now the parameters will keep updating in relation to the scroll direction.

Template:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- overflow:auto; -->
  <div class="scroller-spacer" [ngStyle]="spacerStyle"></div>
  <div class="page-container">
    <div *ngFor="..."></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
  pageStart:number  = 0;
  pageEnd:number    = 50;
  pageHeight:number = 30;
  pageBuffer:number = 50;

  onScroll( event, doc )
  {
    const scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
    const scrollHeight = event.target.scrollHeight;
    const offsetHeight = event.target.offsetHeight;
    const scrollPosition = scrollTop + offsetHeight;
    const scrollTresholdDown = scrollHeight - this.pageHeight;
    const scrollTresholdUp = scrollHeight - (this.pageHeight - this.pageBuffer);

    if( scrollPosition > scrollTresholdDown ){
      this.pageEnd+= this.pageBuffer;
      this.pageStart+= this.pageBuffer; // added this to update pageStart
    }
    else if( scrollPosition < scrollTresholdUp ){
      this.pageEnd-= this.pageBuffer;
      this.pageStart-= this.pageBuffer; // added this to update pageStart
    }
  }
```

I hope this could help with your problem.

gl